# NaN value when using functions in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm currently writing a function that returns NaN. Taken part by part I've found only one source of error.

Here is the relevant code returning NaN :

```
function test() {
  Logger.log(howMuchDamage([[808, 404], [1814, 2595, 0], 0.3869, 0.6802, 0.103, 1], [100000, 10875, [0, 0], [0.1, 0.1], 0, 0], ["FT", "IE", [0, 0.2], 0.2075 * 3, 0.0208 * 3, 0, 0], [0.05], [0.05, 0.05], [0.2,0.05]))
}

function test2() {
  Logger.log(tooltipNumber("FT", [0, 0.2], 0.2075 * 3, 0,0208 * 3, 0, 0, [1814, 2595, 0], [808, 404]))
}

function howMuchDamage(attackerStats, targetStats, abilityData, multiplicative, additive, critIncrease) {
  var damage = 0
  var crit = 0
  var hit = didItHit(attackerStats[5], targetStats[2], abilityData[0])
  if(hit === 1) {
    damage = tooltipNumber(abilityData[0], abilityData[3], abilityData[4], abilityData[5], abilityData[6], attackerStats[1], attackerStats[0])
    crit = didItCrit(attackerStats[3] + critIncrease[0], targetStats[4], abilityData[1])
    if(crit === 1) {
      damage *= criticalDamage(attackerStats[4] + critIncrease[1], attackerStats[3] + critIncrease[0])
    }
    else if (crit === -1) {
      crit = 0
      damage *= (1 - targetStats[5])
    }
    //Multiply damage by the multipliers through an array with all the relevant multipliers and apply DR.
    damage *= multiplicativeMultiplier(multiplicative, additiveMultiplier(additive)) * (1 - totalDR(targetStats[2], targetStats[1], abilityData[1], abilityData[2]))
  }
  return [1, damage, crit, hit]
}

function tooltipNumber(type, coefficient, StdHPmin, StdHPdiff, AMP, bonus, weaponDamage) {
  if(type === "MR") {
    return coefficient * bonus[0] + (1 + AMP) * (Math.random() * weaponDamage[1] + weaponDamage[0]) + baseDamageValue * (Math.random() * StdHPdiff + StdHPmin)
  }
  else if(type === "FT") {
    return coefficient * bonus[1] + baseDamageValue * (Math.random() * StdHPdiff + StdHPmin)
  }
  else if(type === "heal") {
    return coefficient * bonus[2] + baseHealingValue * (Math.random() * StdHPdiff + StdHPmin)
  }
  else {
    return coefficient * bonus[1] + baseDamageValue * (Math.random() * StdHPdiff + StdHPmin)
  }
}
```

`howMuchDamage` should return a list of numbers (integer for everything but damage). `damage` is NaN.

I have reduced the problem to `damage = tooltipNumber(abilityData[0], abilityData[3], abilityData[4], abilityData[5], abilityData[6], attackerStats[1], attackerStats[0])`. I tried to change it to `damage = 5000` and it still returned NaN.
`tooltipNumber` is also returning NaN. Everything seems fine tho. Only floats or integers are ever added. The only string is in the `if` condition.

Comment: What's google-apps-script about this question? If I'm not missing anything, this is pure javascript.

Comment: @Adelin - Mainly done in Google Apps Script, but I know Javascript, and both are pretty much the same.. And Logger.log is GAS, not Javascript.
I just can't find what exactly is causing me to get a NaN when everything I use are numbers.

Comment: Anyway, I'd like to help pinpoint the issue, but without `didItHit`, `multiplicativeMultiplier` and other similar functions that I see called there I can't replicate the bug on my side. You pass some strings to the functions. Perhaps one of those is wrongly treated as number in those calculations, which is why you get `NaN`

Comment: @Adelin - All of them are wai. I tested them all and they all returned what I expected.
But if they are needed... Here's the full script : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Tb7QiYROJdDCmD1VVgn-FPxTIVDNkG5Q8mpfOjnLIOJG3NY07tVzXhlw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking into [the link with all the code](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Tb7QiYROJdDCmD1VVgn-FPxTIVDNkG5Q8mpfOjnLIOJG3NY07tVzXhlw), I noticed the problem.

The issue comes from `totalDR`.

When you call it, you pass `targetStats[2]` as `damageReduction`
You use this `damageReduction` later, by adding it to `armorContribution`.

But `damageReduction` is an array (`[0, 0]`), so you can't just  do `damageReduction + armorContribution`

This returns `NaN` and needs to be fixed..